# Designing a Turing machine which recognises that doubles the input string and concatenates the invert of the input

Tags: turing-machines

I have to design a Turing machine which takes a input string $a^{*}$.

$a^{*} = \left \{0,1  \right \}^{+}$

Following this pattern where S is the input string:

$$
S_{n} = \left \{0, n=0  \right \} \\ \\ S_{n} = \left \{S_{n-1} \overline{S_{n-1}}, n>0  \right \} \\ 
$$
The overline meaning that part will be inverted

Example: $input \mapsto output$

$$ 
\epsilon  \mapsto 0 \\
a \mapsto S_{0}\overline{S_{0}}=0\overline{0}=01\\
aa \mapsto S_{1}\overline{S_{1}}=01\overline{01}=0110\\
aaa \mapsto S_{2}\overline{S_{2}}=0110\overline{0110}=01101001
$$

I have a hard time knowing where to start and how to figure out how the head moves over the tape and what procedure to proceed with. Let me know if there's something unclear about my question and I will happily answer.

Comment: Well, imagine *you* are the Turing machine. Takes a piece of paper, draw a line of squares, and write $aaa$. Then mechanically follow the recipe, where from do you copy the information, where does it go?

Comment: Surely all quetions that ask to design a specific Turing machine performing a silly task must be either homeowork or a past exam question?